# Laragon: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)

Tags: mysql, database, localhost, telnet, laragon

A couple days ago i created a new wordpress project in Laragon and everything done smoothly.

3 days ago when i was trying to access my project, it suddenly shows like this:
[Error establishing a database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufSC.png)

And then i just tried to create a new wordpress project again and it shows me like this:
[Connect to server at localhost failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmQwq.jpg)

Using laragon terminal, i type "telnet localhost 3306" and the result is "connection refused"
[Telnet localhost 3360 via Laragon terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Syt.png)

What should i do to fix this error? Please help me if you know. Thank you!